# for loop; sample median; repeated random sampling

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, statistics

```
repeat = 50
samplesize = 14
samplesize_list = [2, 5, 7] 
std_list = [10, 20, 30]
mean_list = [1000, 2000, 3000]

repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in range(len(samplesize_list)):
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for z in range(len(std_list)):
        std_list = std_list[z]
        for m in range(len(mean_list)):
            mean_list = mean_list[m]
            for i in range(repeat):
                sample_data = np.random.normal(mean_list, std_list, size)
                repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data)
    plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
    sns.distplot(repeat_median, color = 'blue')
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
    plt.show()
```

I have a little problem with the for loop in my code. I'm trying to find the sample distribution of the sample median using repeated random sampling of 50 different outcomes. So I should only have a single graph displaying the distribution of the sample median of 14 samples (3 different sub groups (2, 5, 7) that makes up the 14 samples are each normally distributed with their own mean and standard deviation).

For example: Subgroup of population 2 is normally distributed with standard deviation 10 and mean 1000. Subgroup of population 5 is normally distributed with standard deviation 20 and mean 2000, and so on. How do I loop them together in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered similar question yesterday with a similar output. I am not sure if it was you who posted it again. Nevertheless, there were couple of errors in defining variable in your code. Following is the working version with the output. The modified/added lines are marked by a comment `#`

```
repeat = 50
samplesize = 14
samplesize_list = [2, 5, 7] 
std_list = [10, 20, 30]
mean_list = [1000, 2000, 3000]

repeat_median = np.empty(repeat, dtype = float)
for j in range(len(samplesize_list)):
    size = samplesize_list[j]
    for z in range(len(std_list)):
        std = std_list[z] # modified, you used the same name as variable
        for m in range(len(mean_list)):
            mean = mean_list[m] # modified, you used the same name as variable
            for i in range(repeat):
                sample_data = np.random.normal(mean, std, size)
                repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data)
    plt.subplot(len(samplesize_list), 1, j+1)
    sns.distplot(repeat_median, color = 'blue', label='Size %d'%samplesize_list[j]) # added legend
    plt.legend(loc = "upper right")
plt.tight_layout() # added for better subplot adjustment
```

**Output**

[image]

---

**A less verbose way of writing your code using list comprehensions**

```
for j, size in enumerate(samplesize_list):
    for z, std in enumerate(std_list):
        for m, mean in enumerate(mean_list):
            for i in range(repeat):
                sample_data = np.random.normal(mean, std, size)
                repeat_median[i] = np.median(sample_data)
```

Comment: what if say, I want a single graph displaying the sample distribution of the sample median of sample size 14? and not the sample distribution of the sample median in each subgroups.